# How to remove new lines in a string using the processing language?

Tags: string, text, newline, processing

Is it possible to remove the newline ('\n') character from strings in processing.

e.g.

```
'hello,
how are you,
that's nice.'
```

turns into

```
'hello, how are you, that's nice'
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular language you want to do this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is based on Java you can use all methods from the [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). For example:

```
String s = "hello,\nhow are you,\nthat's nice.";
s = s.replace('\n', ' ');
println(s);
```